# How do I hide columns in OpenXML spreadsheet using C#?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I'm using DocumentFormat.OpenXML with C#. How do I hide specific columns?
Some part of the code:

```cs
using (SpreadsheetDocument sDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(resultFileName, true))
{
    WorkbookPart workbookPart = sDocument.WorkbookPart;
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();

    var relId = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart);

    GenerateWorksheetPartContent(worksheetPart, data, templateSheet);

    var columns = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Column>(); <-- Empty

    int[] colomnsToHide = new int[] { 3, 8, 16, 17, 18 };

    foreach (int i in colomnsToHide)
    {
        columns[i].Hidden = true;
    }
}
```

templateSheet - SheetData from xlsx-template.
data - data to insert.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

The Column descendant is only added to the worksheetpart when there is some custom column behavior, such as sizes, hiding, or grouping.  You can explicitly add column definitions like this:

```
Columns columns = new Columns();

// Min & Max refer to the 1-indexed column ordinal
Column column3 = new Column(){ Min = 3, Max = 3, Width = 0, CustomWidth = true, Hidden = true };
Column column8 = new Column(){ Min = 8, Max = 8, Width = 0, CustomWidth = true, Hidden = true };
// ... repeat for each column

columns.Append(column3);
columns.Append(column8);
worksheetPart.Append(columns);
```

Do this for each column you wish to hide

Comment: You've probably had in mind Worksheet? I opened my template file in Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool and used the logic from there:  
<!-- language: c# -->

    `public Worksheet GenerateWorksheet()
    {
        Worksheet worksheet1 = new Worksheet();
        ....
        Columns columns1 = new Columns();
        ....
        worksheet1.Append(columns1);
        ....
        return worksheet1;
    }`

Comment: To get this to work, I had to insert it after the SheetFormatProperties object:

`worksheetPart.Worksheet.InsertAfter(columns, worksheetPart.Worksheet.SheetFormatProperties);`

Comment: Also don't forget to call worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save() method if AutoSave is not enabled for document.